# Build conda package from a local C++ program

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda, conda-build

I am trying to build (and later upload) a conda package which would contain my custom program that I have developed in C++.
Simplifying the problem, I have a following `meta.yaml`:

```
package:
  name: CoolName
  version: "1.0.0"

source:
  path: ./source

requirements:
  build:
    - make
```

and the following `build.sh`:

```
make
```

I have two questions here:
1) How and where should I copy the binary which is a result of the `make` compilation so that it is indeed recognized upon environment activation?
2) How should I specify g++ as a dependancy? I would like to have this package be later available for `linux-64` and `osx-64`... In the building process (in the Makefile) I am using only g++.

---

#### Edit

I have modified my build script to have:

```
make
mkdir -p $PREFIX/bin
cp my_binary $PREFIX/bin/my_binary
```

And now the `conda-build` is successful. However, when I later try to install the package locally with `conda install --use-local` I get:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

But this is not true, my binary is not installed anywhere and is not recognized...

Comment: I am trying to convert a local C++ library into a conda package, something similar to what you have done. Is it possible for you to share your process/code repo for reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How and where should I copy the binary which is a result of the make compilation so that it is indeed recognized upon environment activation?

As you mentioned in your edit, install somewhere within `${PREFIX}`

> 2. How should I specify g++ as a dependancy?

To use conda-supplied compilers (rather than your system compiler), use this:

```yaml
requirements:
  build:
    - {{ compiler('cxx') }}
```

> I would like to have this package be later available for linux-64 and osx-64... In the building process (in the Makefile) I am using only g++.

Note: On Mac, it will use `clang++`, not `g++`.  Make sure your Makefile respects the `${CXX}` environment variable instead of hard-coding `g++`.

> However, when I later try to install the package locally with `conda install --use-local` I get:

That is strange.  `conda install --use-local CoolName` should do what you want.  But here are some things to try:

- Double-check the contents of the environment you're trying to install it into:

  ```
    conda list
  ```
- Try installing to a fresh environment:

  ```
    conda create -n my-new-env --use-local CoolName
  ```
- Delete any obsolete versions of the package you might have created before you successfully built the package:

```
# Inspect the packages you've created,
# and consider deleting all but the most recent one.
ls $(conda info --base)/conda-bld/linux-64/CoolName*.tar.bz2
```

...then try running `conda install` again.

Comment: Thank you!
I removed everything, build a new `env` just with my program and it works!